# Why am I getting a "No owner defined between domain classes.." error?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm just learning Grails and I've went through quite a few duplicate Stack Overflow questions but haven't been able to find a solution to this issue.

I have three domain classes:

```
class Album {

    String name
    Date releaseDate

    static belongsTo = Artist
    static hasMany = [tracks:Track, artists:Artist]

    static constraints = {
        name blank: false
        releaseDate blank:false
        tracks minSize:1
        artists minSize:1       
    }
}
```

..

```
class Track {

    static belongsTo = Album

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

..

```
class Artist {

    String name;

    static hasMany = [ albums:Album ]

    static constraints = {
        name blank:false
    }
}
```

Running the following grails command generates the error:

`generate-all Album`

```
Error loading plugin manager: No owner defined between domain classes [class musicservice.Album] and [class musicservice.Artist] in a many-to-many relationship. Example: static belongsTo = musicservice.Artist (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Tbe way to map a many-to-many in GORM is to define a `hasMany` on each side, but one side needs to be the 'owning' side, so you have to add a `belongsTo` property on the 'owned' side. Since Artist has-many Albums, and Album has-many Artists, Grails wants you to define the owned side for this many-to-many.

You can read more about this [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany).

Comment: Album does have a belongsTo = Artist. Looks like the problem was caused by not using the fully qualified package name though.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the full package name in the Grails command.

`grails generate-all musicservice.Album`